# Rails: Sidekiq cannot find the created record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using sidekiq to run some job after creating a record. when the job tries to find the record with the created ID, there are random cases where it raises a `RecordNotFound`. how can this be possible?

```
class Person
  def self.test_create
    p = Person.create(
      name: 'test'
    )

    p.run_on_sidekiq
  end

  def run_on_sidekiq
    PersonJob.perform_async(self.id)
  end
end

# Sidekiq runs on other server.
class PersonJob
  def perform(id)
    person = Person.find(id) # sometimes raises RecordNotFound!

    # ...
    # do something
    # ...
  end
end
```

EDIT: as per [Alexei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273444/alexey-shein)'s answer, this case was more related with Sidekiq. edited the question to add more detail on Sidekiq usage.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am running into the same issue! I am passing on the ID to the Sidekiq worker and that id does work with queries outside of the worker, just not inside of the worker.

Answer (score 8):

This is a common case when you're [using Sidekiq in `after_create`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq) hooks. What is actually going on is that Sidekiq starts working before the transaction has been finished, that's why it can't find model in database (and also because it's so blazingly fast). What you need to do is to change your `after_create` hook to `after_commit` which ensures that transaction has been finished.

If you show your exact code that uses Sidekiq, I can elaborate more about your specific usage.

UPDATE:
This is strange, your current code should be fine, since calling `save/destroy` already [gets wrapped](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Transactions::ClassMethods-label-save+and+destroy+are+automatically+wrapped+in+a+transaction) in a transaction.

One reason I can think about is validation error. If your `Person.create` call fails in some way, you'll get back an instance of `Person` where `id` would be `nil`. This way, Sidekiq will try to find a record with `id=nil` and will throw an error.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more details. however, I am not using an `after_create` hook. I am sending the issued ID to sidekiq after create returns. Is using `after_commit` the only way to make sure the record has been created?

Answer (score 1):

`create` doesn't guarantee also it will roll-back silently, if there are any errors.

`create!` would raise an `exception` on failing condition.

What I would think the ideal way to call your method is to check if object is `persisted?` against database.

```
 def test_create
   person = Person.create(name: 'test')
   person.some_method if person.persisted?
 end
```

Other way:

```
person.some_method unless person.errors.any?
```