# Sidekiq not finding id even after transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

In the code example below, when the publish (`:message_created`) is received by the subscriber (a sidekiq worker) the first time it is run it cannot find the id.

```rb
class ChatRoom < ApplicationRecord
  #... 
  def add_message(args)
    #...

    message = self.messages.create!(
      #...
    )

    publish(:message_created,
      message_id: message.id,
      notify: notify
    )
  end
end


class Messages::Notify < ApplicationSubscriber
  include Wisper::Publisher
  def message_created(args)
    internal_note = InternalNote.find(args[:message_id])
    #...
  end
end
```

I'm aware that this is noted in the docs ([Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#cannot-find-modelname-with-id12345))

The subscriber receives the id and on the re-run of the job it works. When forcing the `create!` to be surrounded by a transaction block it still has the same issue:

```rb
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  def create!(args)
    self.transaction do
      super(args)
    end
  end
end
```

We are unable to move the publish to the after_commit inside the message class as we require some additional info inside the ChatRoom class

(*I know it works eventually :) but our error logging is spammed so I would like to understand and solve this issue*)

Comment: Where / how is `add_message` called? Maybe the call is already wrapped inside a (larger) transaction.

Comment: Check if this answers your query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604401/18653817

Comment: @SachinSingh

Not quite, we receive the id so it is not falling and we are not using the hook in our case

Comment: @Stefan you were spot on!! Thanks, explained in the answer

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion in the comments, the answer was that the item calling `add_message` was wrapped in a transaction

As per the rails [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#label-Nested+transactions):

`transaction` calls can be nested. By default, this makes all database statements in the nested transaction block become part of the parent transaction

So the publish would fire off but the parent transaction was still locked.

Comment: You can "fix" the problem by publishing after the parent transaction is committed.